# yii2-websocket issue for getting online users list

Tags: websocket, yii2

I am using this [package](https://github.com/consik/yii2-websocket) for a chat application. I am facing issue to get the online users list. There is a way suggested by someone I tried that but no success.

Code below for getting the online users list.

```
/**
 * Subscribe to messages
 *
 * @param ConnectionInterface $client
 * @param string              $msg
 */
public function commandSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $client, $msg)
{
    $request = @json_decode($msg, true);

    $client->talkId = $request['talk_id'] ?? null;
    $client->userId = $request['user_id'] ?? null;
    $this->clients = $client;
    foreach ($this->clients as $key=>$chatClient) {
         $onlineUsers[] = $chatClient->name;
    }
    $client->send( json_encode(['onlineUsers'=> $onlineUsers, 'room'=>$client->talkId, 'user' =>$client->userId ,'message'=> 'User added to room']) );
}
```

I get the below response:

> Response:{"onlineUsers":{},"room":"provider","user":"hassan","message":"User added to room"}

Comment: the response shows there arent any users , validate what does `$this->clients` hold

Comment: It's a protected member of the class.  That contains the information of all users. It's working for sending messages to different clients but when we try to get online users it does not work and return an empty response. `protected $clients` You can check the package example.